# Check - Compare > Update SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I would like to write a stored procedure where I can update a table based on following criteria.

```
Table 
EmployeeID  GroupID Group#
123     G123        3
456     G456        3
789     G789        3
101     G101        3

View
GroupID_Granular    GroupID_Middle  GroupID_Executive
G123            M123            E123
G789            M789            E789
```

If GroupID is found in View’s GroupID_Granular column, update the table, set GroupID = GroupID_Executive and set the Group# to 1.

I am not sure how to check/compare and then run Update cmd.

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done easily with a `JOIN`:

```
UPDATE t
SET 
    t.GroupID = v.GroupID_Executive, 
    t.[Group#] = 1
FROM YourTable t
JOIN YourView v ON v.GroupID_Granular = t.GroupID
```

### [Sql Fiddle Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/26761/2)